# Characters in XML of POST Body not being escaped

Tags: asp.net, http, post, webrequest

I'm trying to send a stream of xml in a POST request to a REST endpoint like so...

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlUrl);
var stringData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(xmlForm);
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xform=" + stringData);
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en-CA,*");
var newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
await newStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And the problem that I am running into is that when I check Fiddler the body is fragmented because the ampersand in "&amp" values are not being escaped and I'm not sure how to fix this.

The body end up fragmented like this...

[image]

Comment: So just that I understand this correctly: You are sending that XML document out as a parameter to an urlencoded `POST` request?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlUrl);
 var stringData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(xmlForm);

 stringData = "xform=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(stringData);

 var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.KeepAlive = true;
 request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
 request.ContentLength = data.Length;
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
 request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en-CA,*");
 var newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 await newStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The problem was that i needed to UrlEncode the data in order for it not to be interpreted.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What kept you from sending XML directly?

Comment: like by "application/xml" ?

Comment: By exactly that.

Comment: I'm trying to interface with some third party REST API and it seems that this is how they want it. :/

Comment: Well, REST does not extend to the structure of message bodies. So it's odd but not entirely unreasonable.

Comment: I'm glad someone else found it odd